# How to put RegularExpressionValidator for phone number

Tags: asp.net, regex

In asp.net, I want to use `regularexpressionvalidator` for phone number. requirement is only to allow numbers and Dash (-)

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ErrorMessage="Not a Valid Phone Number" ValidationExpression="\d*">
```

The above code only validates numbers but not Dash `-`. Like user randomly put
23333-34 (should accept) or any combination. It is not must that - will be there. It can be numbers only some times.

Comment: Have you tried the regular expression validator of Asp.net, Validation expression "^[0-9]{10}$".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this as the ValidationExpression:

```
 [0-9-]*
```

to accept any number of digits and dashes (including "---").
You could also use this:

```
 ([0-9]\-?)*
```

to accept digits, optionally with single *dashes* inbetween (or after). Use `{5,10}` instead of `*` to accept a minimum of 5 and a maximum of 10 digits (adjust the numbers to your needs).

For more regex info, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Comment: +1 for your useful post. By the way, is it possible to combine what you have given above with checking whether the input starts with 8 or 9?

Comment: @user3437460 - yes, add `[89]` before the regex, to require an `8` or `9` as first character.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I figured out an alternative using `^[89]\d{7}` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reg" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VGrp"
    SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Phone is invalid"
    ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ValidationExpression="\d*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

try this.

Comment: I have tried the above code. This is tracking the numbers but not the dash (-)